# Cannot set animation duration

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Good day, everyone!

Well, i've got a very simple trouble.
I've got a CATransformLayer with two sublayers, each with "false" doubleSided property, and this forms a double-sided card. 
The problem is, that i cannot set the animation duration or any other options, like, for example, UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut etc. 
I tried new and old one method to add animation options and duration to my layer, but, unfortunately, it rotates about 0,25 seconds, as the default value states. What's wrong? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here 's the code :

1) Initialization of all the stuff :

```
    #ifndef SUPPORTED_MACRO
    #define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) (angle * M_PI / 180.0)
    #endif
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
          [super viewDidLoad];

          [super viewDidLoad];

          CATransformLayer *cardContainer = [CATransformLayer layer];
          cardContainer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake( 0.5 , 1.0 ) ;
          cardContainer.position = CGPointMake(100.0, 200.0) ;
          cardContainer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 150.0, 170.0);

          CALayer *cardFront  = [CALayer layer]; // the front part of card
          cardFront.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, cardContainer.bounds.size.width,     cardContainer.bounds.size.height) ;
          cardFront.frame = cardContainer.bounds ;
          cardFront.contentsGravity  = kCAGravityResizeAspect ;
          cardFront.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
          cardFront.borderWidth = 2.0;
          cardFront.cornerRadius = 30.0;
          [cardContainer addSublayer:cardFront];

          CALayer *cardBack  = [CALayer layer]; //back part of card
          cardBack.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, cardContainer.bounds.size.width, cardContainer.bounds.size.height) ;
          cardBack.frame     = cardContainer.bounds;
          cardBack.contentsGravity  = kCAGravityResizeAspect ;
          cardBack.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
          cardBack.borderWidth = 2.0;
          cardBack.cornerRadius = 30.0;
          cardBack.doubleSided = NO;

 cardBack.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(180.0),0.0,1.0,0.0);
[cardContainer addSublayer:cardBack];

((CALayer*)[cardContainer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0]).contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"].CGImage ;
((CALayer*)[cardContainer.sublayers objectAtIndex:1]).contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"].CGImage ;

          TL = cardContainer ;
          [self.view.layer addSublayer:cardContainer];

 }
```

2) Procedure to rotate  ( in a deprecated style) :

```
    -(void)Rotate
    {
          static double CallCounter = 1.0 ;

          auto CATransform3D t3d = CATransform3DIdentity;
          t3d.m34 = 1.0/-500.0;

          [UIView  beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
          [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
          [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.75];
          TL.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DRotate(t3d, -(CallCounter*M_PI) , 1.0, 0.0, 0.0) ;
          [UIView commitAnimations];

          CallCounter += 1.0 ;

}
```

Comment: Where are you calling rotate from?

Comment: From the following routine :


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   [self Rotate] ;
}

Comment: Also, what if you call `setAnimationDuration` before you call `setAnimationCurve`?

Comment: well, doesn't help, i guess because the animation attaches only after     [UIView commitAnimations];
state

Comment: Did you try using the block based animation methods to see if they take your paramenters? `animateWithDuration:animations:`, etc.

Comment: yep, i did : 

            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.75 delay:0.0 options:nil      animations:^{
            auto CATransform3D t3d = CATransform3DIdentity;
            t3d.m34 = 1.0/-500.0;
            TL.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DRotate(t3d, - (CallCounter*M_PI) , 1.0, 0.0, 0.0) ;

          }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         
                     }
             ] ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem was very simple. The thing is, that not every property of an object can be animated. For example, we can't animate this expression :

```
   int *a = ( int* ) malloc ( 5 * sizeof ( int ) ) ;
```

Or this :

```
   int x = 5 ;
```

Or, finally, this :

```
    TL.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DRotate(t3d, -(CallCounter*M_PI) , 1.0, 0.0, 0.0) ;
```

Cause the idea of transform property is to generate a matrix, that will be written to sublayerTransfrom class field. And, basically for the compiler, it's the same expression, as malloc call, or initialising x variable - it's an assigment operation. It looks like, CATransformLayer class has some kind of checker, which is being called only if the property changes it's value. Cocoa will automatically send messages when a property changes. by a Key-Value Observation mechanism.

So, to animate this non-animatable property, i decided to use CATransaction blocks. They're really helpfull in such situations. Hope, someone will find this post useful! Sorry for my English, i'm from Russia)